# How to debug unknown error in NLU Watson API?

Tags: python, watson, watson-nlu

I am streaming tweets and storing them in a text file. Then there is a python script running simultaneously which reads tweets from the text file and processes them eventually saving the Watson's results in a csv file. How should one debug such error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "processingTweets.py", line
>   47, in 
>       language='en'   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/watson_developer_cloud/natural_language_understanding_v1.py",
>   line 173, in analyze
>       method='POST', url=url, params=params, json=data, accept_json=True)   File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/watson_developer_cloud/watson_service.py",
>   line 385, in request
>       info=error_info, httpResponse=response) watson_developer_cloud.watson_service.WatsonApiException: Error:
>   Unknown error, Code: 500 , X-dp-watson-tran-id: gateway01-1812171421 ,
>   X-global-transaction-id: 7ecac92c5adf6c0a6c038a9d

Comment: Does it succeed if you retry the request?  A 500 error corresponds to "internal server error" and is usually a transient failure.

Comment: Yes, I am able to restart the program and run it successfully for almost 4 or 5 hours straight. However, I did not change anything and am unable to comprehend as to how an internal server error would have been caused.

Comment: Internal error is caused by a problem with the service itself; for example, a server crash.  Generally, you should simply wait a few seconds and then retry if you encounter an error between 500-599.

Comment: So, what should I do in order to have my program run continuously? Is there anything that restarts it once the error is generated and caused my program to stop?

Comment: You need a `try` / `catch` block in your code around the call.  If you catch an exception, sleep for two seconds and then try again.

Comment: @idfah
Can you please asnwer, the same comment? I have to accept it. Thanks :)